# How to categorize data from 1 column into a new variable in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame (my_data) on tumors that occur in children and adolescents and each tumor has a specific code. However, the tumors can be grouped into 12 main groups. The numbers 11 t/m 20 correspond with "I", numbers between 20 and 30 correspond with "II" (and this continues till we reach "XII").

At this moment, my data includes the numbers (11t/m 122). I need to categorize these into the twelve main groups, and add these as a separate column (which includes the values "I" t/m "XII").

These are my first 10 rows, to give you an idea of the data.

```
my_data

       key_P   key_T new_icccmain
       <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>
 1  96111201 5677620          112
 2 654431201 7250720           21
 3  39341201 6261720          116
 4 146291201 1087720          103
 5  38302201 2429720           32
 6 672112201 7020820          116
 7 125612201 3670820          114
 8 561352201 7615820           22
 9 721652201 8755820           94
10 320562201 7566820          103
```

I have tried the following (but I'm not an expert as you might see):

```
if (my_data$new_icccmain<20){
  my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- "I"
} else if (my_data$new_icccmain > 20 & my_data$new_icccmain < 30) {
  my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- "II"
} else if (my_data$new_icccmain > 30 & my_data$new_icccmain < 40) {
  my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- "III"
} else if (my_data$new_icccmain > 40 & my_data$new_icccmain < 49) {
  my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- "IV"
} else if (my_data$new_icccmain == 50) {
  my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- "V"
} else if (my_data$new_icccmain > 60 & my_data$new_icccmain < 70) {
  my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- "VI"
} else if (my_data$new_icccmain > 70 & my_data$new_icccmain < 80) {
  my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- "VII"
} else if (my_data$new_icccmain > 80 & my_data$new_icccmain < 90) {
  my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- "VIII"
} else if (my_data$new_icccmain > 90 & my_data$new_icccmain < 100){
  my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- "IX"
} else if (my_data$new_icccmain > 100 & my_data$new_icccmain < 110) {
  my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- "X"
} else if (my_data$new_icccmain > 110 & my_data$new_icccmain < 120) {
  my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- "XI"
} else {
  my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- "XII"
}
```

I receive the following warning from R: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. I have no clue what to do!

Can you please help me out?? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `case_when()` function from the `dplyr` package is useful here:

```
my_data$maindiagnosticgr <- dplyr::case_when(my_data$new_icccmain < 20 ~ "I",
                                             my_data$new_icccmain < 30 ~ "II",
                                             my_data$new_icccmain < 40 ~ "III",
                                             my_data$new_icccmain < 49 ~ "IV",
                                             my_data$new_icccmain == 50 ~ "V",
                                             my_data$new_icccmain < 70 ~ "VI",
                                             my_data$new_icccmain < 80 ~ "VII",
                                             my_data$new_icccmain < 90 ~ "VIII",
                                             my_data$new_icccmain < 100 ~ "IX",
                                             my_data$new_icccmain < 110 ~ "X",
                                             my_data$new_icccmain < 120 ~ "XI",
                                             TRUE ~ "XII")
```